MySql Docker Container : Max query size reached (at file /tmp/schema/schema.sql)
I've a mysql docker container in which I'm need to push a local database dump which is 419KB in size.
I'm using docker desktop in  windows 10.
The Problem - 
When turning the container up, using docker-compose up --build, a few of the tables don't populate in the container's database. I have a 24 tables in my local db but only 22 of them get populated in the container db.
I've received the following error message in the mysql-container-console - 
My Approach - 
I am thinking that mysql container runs out of memory while setting up the database from the db dump. To fix that, I've tried the following-

Increasing the containers memory by using the max_allocate_packet argument using the following command - docker run -it -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw mysql:5.7 --max-allowed-packet=67108864 but this didn't help.
using .wslconfig file

After using the .wslconfig file, these are the docker stats - 
which shows, for mysql container, the mem usage is 427MB and the limit is 3+ GB.
My db dump file is only 419KB in size even then mysql container is not able to process it successfully.
It would be really appreciable if someone could help me to fix this issue.
